# Django как добавить в базу несколько записей сразу

Tags: django

В общем мне нужно последовательно добавлять много данных в базу. Если каждый раз создавать объект и сохранять сразу его, то сохранение очень сильно затягивается, как сделать это быстрее? То есть в массив как бы добавить все эти объекты и одним разом сохранить. А то кажется мне на каждый запрос идет авторизация в mysql, что и забирает время

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
    Entry(headline='This is a test'),
    Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
])
```